# How do I verify the energy conservation rate for the total energy?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's given differential equation

$\dot{x}=p$

$\dot{p}=-x^3+x$

How do I verify the energy conservation rate for the total energy?

$H(x,p)=\frac{x^4}{4}-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{p^2}{2}+\frac{1}{2}$?

What follows for the solution curves of the differential equation?

I have found on internet that if I want to check  energy conservation, I need to verify that

$0=\frac{dH}{dt}=\frac{dH}{dx}\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dH}{dp}\frac{dp}{dt}$

I'm not sure if this equation  is good, but if it is, what is my $t$ here?

Comment: Just to check, should $H$ be a function of $x$ and $p$? Or $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Thank you. It's my mistake it should be function of $x$ and $p$. @TroyG

Comment: Also, should the $\dot{y}$ be $\dot{p}$ instead then? Anyway, to check if energy conserved, you are right in saying that you need to verify $\frac{dH}{dt}=0$. It does not matter what $t$ is, because $\frac{dx{dt} = \dot{x}$, which is already given in the first instance. All you need to do is to differentiate $H$ with respect to $x$ and $p$ and substitute the relevant expressions into your last equation.

Comment: No it shouldn't be. What follows for the solution curves of the differential equation? What should I do here?

Comment: When i differentiale with respect to $x$ I get $x^3+x$ and to respect to $p$ I get only $p$ so .... I don't think this is good @TroyG

Answer (score 2):

You should get the identities of Hamiltonian vector fields resp. H~ mechanics 
$$
\dot x=H_p,\ \  \dot p = -H_x
$$ 
which gives you 
$$
\frac{d}{dt}H(x,p)=H_x\dot x+H_p\dot p=H_x\,H_p+H_p\,(-H_x)=0.
$$
Integration of the given equations then gives $$H(x,p)=\frac12p^2+V(x)$$ and from that $$-H_x=-V'(x)=-x^3+x$$ leading to $$V(x)=\frac14x^4-\frac12x^2+C.$$ One may choose $C$ to complete the square so that finally
$$
H(x,p)=\frac12p^2+\frac14(x^2-1)^2.
$$

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question.

Comment: Can you tell me meaning of last equation. What do I prove with that?

Comment: The last is the result of performing your task in the reverse order, i.e., reconstructing $H$. It also demonstrates that your energy function is wrong, since it does not have $p$ in the square. -- It also shows that you have a double well potential leading for small energies to oscillations around $-1$ or $+1$ and for larger energies to oszillations around $0$.

Comment: What does it mean it doesn't have p in the square?

Comment: Check the formula for $H(x,p)$ in your question.

Comment: How do you get that $H_x\dot{x}$ is the $HH_xH_p$?

Comment: Sorry I made another writing mistake it's $\frac{p^2}{2}$

Comment: This was a typo on my side.

Comment: Can you edit your answer because it's $\frac{p^2}{2}$...

Comment: No, the answer is still valid, the energy functions only differ by a constant $\frac14$. For your task you only need to continue to compute $H_x$ and $H_p$ and check that either the Hamilton equations are true or that everything cancels in $\frac{dH}{dt}$.

Comment: It doesn't cancel.

Comment: It should. Add a section to the question telling how far you got.

Comment: When i differentiale with respect to $x$ I get $x^3+x$ and to respect to $p$ I get only $p$ so .... I don't think this is good

Comment: oh that should $p(x^3+x)-p(x^3+x)$?? right? than it's 0?

Comment: Check again, it is $x^3-x$.