# It's given differential equation. How do I determine the solution curve of the begining values $x(0) = 0$,$p(0) = 1$ in the $(x, p)$ plane?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It's given differential equation

$\dot{x}=p$

$\dot{p}=-x^3+x$

How do I determine the solution curve of the begining values $x(0) = 0$,$p(0) = 1$ in the $(x, p)$ plane?

Comment: Weak duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1999288/how-do-i-verify-the-energy-conservation-rate-for-the-total-energy/1999321

Answer (score -1):

As
$$
0=\dot x\dot p - \dot p\dot x=p\dot p+(x^3-x)\dot x
$$
solutions satisfy
$$
2p^2+(x^2-1)^2=C
$$
and for the given initial values $C=2·1^2+(0-1)^2=3$.

Comment: But that's not solution curve?

Comment: It is the equation of the solution curve in the $(x,p)$ plane. Solve $\dot x=\pm\sqrt{\frac12(3-(x^2-1)^2)}$ for the solution.

Comment: How do you get $2p^2+(x^2-1)^2=C$???

Comment: By integrating the previous equation(multiplying with 4) and completing the square. See also the related question.

Comment: Hm, I don't how to integrate this? @LutzL

Comment: Can you help me with this integration little bit @LutzL

Comment: That's the same like H, but why that equals to C @LutzL

Comment: You get $\int 0 dt=\int 4pdp+\int (4x^3-4x)dx$ where you now can adjust integration constants to fit your favorite form.

Comment: Why integral from 0? And why 4? @LutzL

Comment: You've got to do everything the same on both sides. 4 -- to avoid fractions, it is not relevant for the geometrical shape.

Comment: why i integrate $0=p+(-x^3+x)$ @LutzL

Comment: I used that $\int p\dot p\,dt=\int p\,dp =\frac12p^2+C$ etc.